# Pagination of search form results returns nothing for subsequent pages (Kaminari + Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

So I have a search form that returns a Kaminari paginated array. The first page always returns a list of results, however the "GET" of all subsequent page links returns no results and I'm not sure why!

**Here are my search methods in my controller**

```
def writer_search
  @writers = Kaminari.paginate_array(@results).page(params[:page]).per(10)
end

def writer_search_submit
  @results = #my big array of results, this part works fine
  @writers = Kaminari.paginate_array(@results).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  render 'writer_search'
end
```

**View Code**

```
 =form_tag(writer_search_submit_path, :method => 'post') do
   %input{:name => 'keywords', :id => 'keywords', :value => params[:keywords]}
   = submit_tag "Search"

 - @writers.each do |writer|
   #show the results

 = paginate @writers
```

**Server Log when clicking a pagination link**

```
Started GET "/editors/writer_search?commit=Search&keywords=business&page=2"
  Processing by EditorsController#writer_search as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Search", "keywords"=>"business", "page"=>"2", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

The first rendered page has the first 10 results of my array (in this case, there are hundreds of results). Clicking on any of the pagination links makes a GET and returns a page with no results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have `@results` defined in `writer_search_submit` but not `writer_search`.

The GET request to `"/editors/writer_search?commit=Search&keywords=business&page=2"` goes through `EditorsController#writer_search` where `@results` is undefined (and so you get a page with no results).

**Update:** (Thanks Thilo)

Perhaps you could use a before_filter to load @results for all the actions that need it?

Comment: This seems correct, but don't store data in the session unless you absolutely have to. Use a `before_filter` to load @results for all the actions that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't render the search results on an actually search page but on the default index page of whatever route you're searching for.